# Create Opportunity from Custom Object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

My trigger is giving me an "Illegal assignment from Id to SOBJECT:User' error.

The trigger is supposed to create a new opportunity when the field in the custom object is a certain value. I want to input some fields from the object into the opportunity.

```apex
trigger MDwinning2 on MD_Meeting__c (after update) {
List <Opportunity> oppToInsert = new List <Opportunity> ();
    for (MD_Meeting__c m : Trigger.new) {
    if (m.SAL__c==True) {    
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity ();   
    o.OwnerId = m.Sales_Director__c;
    o.Name = m.Name;
    o.StageName = 'Generate Opportunity';
    o.Market_Developer__c = m.Market_Developer__c;
    o.AccountId = m.Account__c;
    o.Type = 'Sales - New Business';
  o.CloseDate = System.Today()+150;
  o.MeetingLookup__c = m.Id;
    oppToInsert.add(o);
    }//end if
}//end for o
//try {
//        insert oppToInsert; 
//    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
//       system.debug (e);
//    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    o.Owner = m.Sales_Director__c;
    o.Account = m.Account__c;
```

To

```
o.OwnerId = m.Sales_Director__c;
o.AccountId = m.Account__c;
```

Comment: I did that and now I'm getting an error that says "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SOBJECT: Opportunity].add(SOBJECT:Opportunity)"

Comment: Change o.add(o); To oppToInsert.add(o);

Comment: Thank you. I made that change as well as changing the MeetingLookup from Name to ID. o.MeetingLookup__c = m.Id    Now there are no errors, but the trigger doesnt actually create an opportunity. Nothing happens.

Comment: @user3112735 Did you test on update operation or insert? Did you considered that you trigger works for update only?

Comment: @pavel Yes. Either way it does not do anything. It lets you update/create the custom object fine, but does not create an opportunity.

Comment: @user3112735 what is in debug log? Might be you catch a DML exception like required_field_missed or any else

Comment: @Pavel Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0r40000005N1WKAA0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MDwinning: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.MDwinning: line 4, column 1: []

Comment: @user3112735 Did you fixed your trouble? If no please update your question with latest versions of meeting & MDwinning trigger's source code because your trouble is in other trigger that posted here right now.

Comment: @Pavel I have updated my code. The trigger is active and without error, but it still does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @user3112735 in updated code your insert operation is commented out

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote this answer for further discussion because the trouble didn't fixed

```apex
trigger MDwinning2 on MD_Meeting__c (after update) {
    List <Opportunity> oppToInsert = new List <Opportunity> ();
    for (MD_Meeting__c m : Trigger.new) {
        if (m.SAL__c == True) {
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity ();
            o.OwnerId = m.Sales_Director__c;
            o.Name = m.Name;
            o.StageName = 'Generate Opportunity';
            o.Market_Developer__c = m.Market_Developer__c;
            o.AccountId = m.Account__c;
            o.Type = 'Sales - New Business';
            o.CloseDate = System.Today() + 150;
            o.MeetingLookup__c = m.Id;
            oppToInsert.add(o);
        }
    }
    insert oppToInsert;
}
```

try this code and if error will appear again please post error msg in comment

Comment: It works now. I was commenting out the insert statement.